# How to remove hyperlinks from an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I would like to know if there is a way to remove hyperlinks from whole Excel file using python only.

P.S. I already have a VBA code that does the task but I would like to automate the process for multiple files,

VBA code:

```
sub Removeallhyperlinks()
    Dim ws as worksheet
    for each ws in Thisworkbook.worksheets
        ws.hyperlinks.delete
    next ws
end sub
```

Comment: Yes this is doable with `win32com` for example.

Comment: can you please elaborate ?